# tkinter menubar and checkbox keep open

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a menubar in `tkinter` in one of the menu in the menu bar, I have some `check_button` and when one of these `check_button` is clicked, the menu closes, but I want to keep this menu open. I want to know if there is a simple way of doing it. I am making a map editor and in my menu I choose to show or not map's elements.

```
menubar = tk.Menu()
viewMenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
viewMenu.add_check_button(label = "Obstacles", varibale = test1)
viewMenu.add_check_button(label = "Ground", varibale = test2)
menubar.add_cascade(menu = viewMenu, label = "View")
win.config(menu = menubar) # win = tk.Tk()
```

Comment: Could you include a code snippet that creates the menu so that we can see what you have so far? This way people who want to help you won't have to start from scratch.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in your questions.

Comment: btw: menu has option `tearoff` so you can tear off  menu (cut off from menubar) and it can stay as popup menu. Atleast it works on Linux.

Comment: @furas thx it's working but not very pretty :/

Comment: maybe it is not very pretty but it's working ;) I susspect to keep menu open would need many, many works - or maybe you would need to write all menu from scratch. But I can be wrong.

Comment: The code above does not work for me so I can't help even though I want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below example opens View back each time a checkbutton is selected:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

test1, test2 = tk.BooleanVar(), tk.BooleanVar()

def cb():
    print(test1.get(), test2.get())
    root.tk.call('::tk::TraverseToMenu', root, 'v')

menubar = tk.Menu(root)
viewMenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
viewMenu.add_checkbutton(label = "Obstacles", variable = test1, command=cb)
viewMenu.add_checkbutton(label = "Ground", variable = test2, command=cb)
menubar.add_cascade(menu = viewMenu, label = "View")
root.config(menu = menubar) # win = tk.Tk()

root.mainloop()
```

See more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47912111/7032856) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47902807/7032856).

---

Based on the answer that accounts for windows' special case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47927605/7032856) a very similar code can be written as follows:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

if root._windowingsystem == 'win32':
    import ctypes

    keybd_event = ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event
    alt_key = 0x12
    key_up = 0x0002

    def traverse_to_menu(key=''):
        if key:
            ansi_key = ord(key.upper())
            #   press alt + key
            keybd_event(alt_key, 0, 0, 0)
            keybd_event(ansi_key, 0, 0, 0)

            #   release alt + key
            keybd_event(ansi_key, 0, key_up, 0)
            keybd_event(alt_key, 0, key_up, 0)

else:
    #   root._windowingsystem == 'x11'
    def traverse_to_menu(key=''):
        root.tk.call('tk::TraverseToMenu', root, key)

test1, test2 = tk.BooleanVar(), tk.BooleanVar()
menubar = tk.Menu(root)
viewMenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
viewMenu.add_checkbutton(label = "Obstacles", variable = test1,
                            command=lambda : traverse_to_menu('v'))
viewMenu.add_checkbutton(label = "Ground", variable = test2,
                            command=lambda : traverse_to_menu('v'))
menubar.add_cascade(menu = viewMenu, label = "View")
root.config(menu = menubar) # win = tk.Tk()

root.mainloop()
```

`key` variable to the `traverse_to_menu` is `'v'` as <kbd>Alt - V</kbd> opens the menu via keyboard. As in `key` needs to be the non-modifying key that by default opens the menu using keyboard.

Comment: I just ran this under Py3, and I don't see the viewMenu reappearing after one of the checkbuttons has been clicked... Is something missing?  I, too, am on Windows (10).  From what I've seen at the two links you reference, people running Linux seem to have better luck with this.  I did try setting tearoff=1, but that had no effect.

Comment: @Gary02127 Thanks to [CommonSense](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6634373/commonsense)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47927605/7032856) I was able to easily modify their code to provide the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I did as follows:

first creating primary things as

```
window=Tk()
mb = Menubutton (window, text="Test", relief=RAISED)
var = BooleanVar()
```

Then adding some checkbutton as below:

```
mb.menu.add_checkbutton(label='Test btn', variable=var,command = lambda: menu_click("some input"))
#adding some other checkbuttons
```

Finally creating menu_click function:

```
def menu_click(input):
   if input == "some input":
      mb.menu.post(mb.winfo_rootx(), mb.winfo_rooty())
```

In which `mb.winfo_rootx(), mb.winfo_rooty()` are x and y coordinates of desired opennig location.

Comment: it's been 3.5 years ... x)