# How to use default bindtag behavior as methods?

Tags: python, tkinter, binding, tcl, tk-toolkit

I am trying to invoke default widget behavior on demand. Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3513906/7032856) I know a bit about bindtags, and taglists.

Let's say for example I have two buttons, and I want to have the bindtag behavior of a specific item in its taglist, of first button, whenever I left click on the right button:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

first_btn = tk.Button(root, text="1st")
second_btn = tk.Button(root, text="2nd")

second_btn.bind("<Button-1>", "expect the bindtag operation here")

first_btn.pack()
second_btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I haven't specified `command=...` for `first_btn` as I need to have the very effect of button push for example with my `second_btn` binding.

---

or as another example, I want to have `second_btn` to invoke all(ideally of my choosing) bindtag callbacks of `first_btn`:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

first_btn = tk.Button(root, text="1st")
second_btn = tk.Button(root, text="2nd", command="first_btn bindtag callbacks")

first_btn.pack()
second_btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

Or, what are reference names(if any) to the operations attached to bindtags?

Comment: I want to do exactly whatever's a widget by default doing on demand. As in I want to see `first_btn` pushed in and back out when I left click on `second_btn`.

Comment: So you just curious about the [`relief`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/relief.html) of the button? You able to control it in your callback. Also, there's an [`invoke`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/button.html) method.

Comment: @CommonSense These are only workarounds to what I exactly want. I want to learn this not only for buttons, but for all default widget behavior. For example there's a bindtag that adds a new line for Text widget when Ctrl - O is pressed for example. Or you can resize treeview columns with mouse drag operations. TL;DR I don't want to mimic what bindtags do, I want to call them on demand to do whatever they're supposed to do.

Comment: There is `first_btn.event_generate('<...>')` to trigger a given event.

Comment: @j_4321 I tried it but it seems to only invoke the callback of `bind`. If you can make it invoke bindtag callbacks please let me know.

Comment: What do you mean by invoke 'bindtags'?

Comment: @j_4321 I mean it seem to only run the callback function defined for an event using `bind` only.

Comment: @j_4321 Hm actually no, it does works pretty well. For buttons I need to add button press and then to mimic delay and release. And it doesn't seem to work with menu though?

Comment: Do you mean it does not work with a `Menu` widget?

Comment: @j_4321 Yes. I'm trying to make items in menu to open the menu when clicked similar to behavior in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47895168/7032856) but I couldn't. Alt-V and Alt-v opens view menu but I when I generate it it doesn't open.

Comment: "Animated behavior" depends on the events, regardless of with which tags these events are tied. You can easily `event_generate` a sequence of `<Button-1>` and `<ButtonRelease-1>` events with a time delay between to "animate" a click. A crude explanation is that under the hood of `tk` to animate these events, each event calls a related function (`tkButtonDown` and `tkButtonUp` respectively). Hence, the only way to animate click without any event and without any "working around" with `relief` is a direct call to the `tkButtonInvoke` function (`root.tk.call('::tk::ButtonInvoke', second_btn)`).

Comment: @CommonSense This seems it. For buttons this seems to do exactly what I want.

Comment: Same applies to all widgets! For example, you could see how interaction of `Menu` and of "Alt-keys" is binded [here](http://core.tcl.tk/tk/artifact/a626a377b36c07d9d6fd99ef8b41bef8fefef25f) (look up for `tk::TraverseToMenu` function).

Comment: @CommonSense Thanks a lot. This is very valuable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To invoke the callback bound to a given sequence (e.g. `<Button-1>`), you can do `widget.event_generate(<sequence>, **kwargs)`. The optional keyword arguments can be `x=0`, `y=0` for a `<Button-1>` event for instance. This will trigger all callbacks associated with the sequence (it does not matter whether they were bound with `bind`, `bind_class` or `bind_all`).

In the below example, when the second button is clicked, it lowers the first one as if it were clicked too:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

first_btn = tk.Button(root, text="1st")
second_btn = tk.Button(root, text="2nd", command=lambda: first_btn.event_generate('<Button-1>'))

first_btn.pack()
second_btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

However, when doing tests interactively from the command line, generating keyboard events often does not work because the widget does not have keyboard focus. So, with the following code, when clicking on the button, the `View` menu will open as if we had done `Alt+v`:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
menubar = tk.Menu(root)
viewMenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
viewMenu.add_command(label="Item 1")
viewMenu.add_command(label="Item 2")
menubar.add_cascade(menu=viewMenu, label="View", underline=0)
root.config(menu=menubar)
tk.Button(root, text='Test', command=lambda: root.event_generate('<Alt-v>')).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

But when I do `root.event_generate('<Alt-v>')` from the IPython QtConsole, nothing happens. The workaround is to force keyboard focus before generating the event:

```
root.focus_force()
root.event_generate('<Alt-v>')
```

Comment: Still can't make it work(nothing happens when the button is clicked) with or without `focus_force`.

Comment: @Nae The piece of code with the menu works for me when I run it, the menu opens both with `Alt-v` and when I click on the button. So I don't know where your problem comes from. I don't know if it is relevant, but I am using linux and tk 8.6.7.

Comment: I'm on Windows 7, python 3.6, and tk 8.6. `Alt-v` opens the menu but the button doesn't seem to do anything. I also tried with defined function that calls those and with lambda [,] way.