# How to view a menu when a button is pressed?

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit

Following up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47902807/7032856), I am trying to view (same as in when clicked with left mouse button) a menu,`sub1`, when a button,`Test`, is pressed, but I can't. In the following code button seems to instead freeze the GUI:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
menubar = tk.Menu(root)

sub1 = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
sub1.add_command(label="Item 1", command=lambda : print("item 1"))
sub1.add_command(label="Item 2", command=lambda : print("item 2"))


menubar.add_cascade(menu=sub1, label="Sub1", underline=0)
root.config(menu=menubar)

def cb(*args):
    root.tk.call('::tk::TraverseToMenu', root, 'S')

tk.Button(root, text="Test", command=cb).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I have also tried `update_idletasks()` to no avail. How can I fix this?

**Tried with:**

> Windows7, Python 3.6, Tkinter 8.6.

Comment: Your code works for me (python3, Debian). What OS are you using?

Comment: Have you [seen this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43355901/how-to-open-a-menu-programmatically-in-python-tkinter)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Trivia

This trick works within the X Window System (read as Unix), because "Alt-keying" is handled by `tk` itself via `tk::TraverseToMenu` function, wich is binded to the `all` bind-tag in that case.

In your case `tk` detects, that it works in `Win` environment, and binds `tk::TraverseToMenu` function only to the `Menubutton` bind-tag, because in such circumstances "Alt-keying" is handled by native `Win` wm.

What was said is represented by the source code in `menu.tcl`:

```
if {[tk windowingsystem] eq "x11"} {
    bind all <Alt-KeyPress> {
    tk::TraverseToMenu %W %A
    }

    bind all <F10> {
    tk::FirstMenu %W
    }
} else {
    bind Menubutton <Alt-KeyPress> {
    tk::TraverseToMenu %W %A
    }

    bind Menubutton <F10> {
    tk::FirstMenu %W
    }
}
```

### Solution

When you press Alt key, Windows [sends a message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx), which signaling that [the Alt-key is pressed down](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms646286(v=vs.85).aspx), and waits [for another message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms646357(v=vs.85).aspx), which contains specified character as ANSI-code.
After a specified character is received, wm is trying to find a menu to open.

In same time `tk::TraverseToMenu` works well - try to pass an empty string or any arbitrary char as a `char` parameter, with wich menu cannot be found. The problem only occurs when you're trying to play on the lawn near the Windows house.

Your best bets in this situation: [SendMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx) or [keybd_event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms646304(v=vs.85).aspx).

So a complete hack (as @Donal Fellows said) is this:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

if root._windowingsystem == 'win32':
    import ctypes

    keybd_event = ctypes.windll.user32.keybd_event
    alt_key = 0x12
    key_up = 0x0002

    def traverse_to_menu(key=''):
        if key:
            ansi_key = ord(key.upper())
            #   press alt + key
            keybd_event(alt_key, 0, 0, 0)
            keybd_event(ansi_key, 0, 0, 0)

            #   release alt + key
            keybd_event(ansi_key, 0, key_up, 0)
            keybd_event(alt_key, 0, key_up, 0)

else:
    #   root._windowingsystem == 'x11'
    def traverse_to_menu(key=''):
        root.tk.call('tk::TraverseToMenu', root, key)

menubar = tk.Menu(root)

sub1 = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
sub1.add_command(label='Item 1', command=lambda: print('item 1'))
sub1.add_command(label='Item 2', command=lambda: print('item 2'))

menubar.add_cascade(menu=sub1, label='Sub1', underline=0)
root.config(menu=menubar)

traverse_button = tk.Button(root, text='Test', command=lambda: traverse_to_menu('S'))
traverse_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Very nice, thanks a lot for your answer! One thing I don't get is why you define functions instead of if/else rather than defining a function with if/else?

Comment: @Nae it's a matter of taste and my habit to separate the os-dependent things like imports. The real question is why a tkinter-generated event like <Alt-v> has no effect, while <Alt-F4> behaves as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The Tkinter buttons aren't supposed to work that way; **that's what a menubutton is for.** But if you're going to continue to hack on a button, you will need to bind to events on the button and not just use the command callback (which is fired off on mouse-button-1 release over the button when the button is armed; arming happens when the mouse-button-1 is pressed over the button).

I really advise using a menubutton ([`tk.Menubutton`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/menubutton.htm)) instead. It's easier for users as it is designed to *look* like it will post a menu when pressed.